# Is text in pdf file is protected?

Tags: windows, pdf, foxit-reader

I have a pdf file written in Vietnamese language. I open it with Foxit Reader and able to read it in Vietnamese.

If I copy the text to Word I can't read the text in Vietnamese any more. Also, when I change mode to Text Viewer Mode in Foxit Reader, I can't read as well.

Is the publisher of pdf have encode their text? Or my computer Window 7 don't have fonts needed to read. If this is the case, how can I find the fonts being used?

Because I can't post images, I quote here extracted text I can't read

> Nhûä  ng   xò-cùng-àan   gêì  n   àêy   trïn   caá c   phûúng   tiïå n   truyïì  n 
>   thöng   àaå i   chuá ng   vïì  Enron,   WorldCom,   Tyco,   ImClone,   Arthur 
>   Anderson,   Martha   Stewart   vaâ           Global   Crossing   laâ      nhûä  ng   caã  nh 
>   baá o maå nh meä   vïì  cuöå c khuã  ng hoaã  ng kyä   nùng laä  nh àaå o hiïå n thúâ  i 
>   trong nïì  n kinh tïë  Myä  . Trïn thûå c tïë  , söë  lûúå ng caá c CEO bõ sa thaã  i 
>   vò yïë u keá m àaä   tùng àïë n 130% trong voâ  ng saá u nùm qua. Roä   raâ  ng, 
>   haâ  ng ngaâ  n doanh nhên vaâ  nhên viïn trong caá c cöng ty nhû vêå y 
>   àïì  u coá  thïí  nhêå n àûúå c nhûä  ng lúå i ñch tûâ  caá c chiïë n lûúå c, yá  tûúã  ng 
>   laä  nh àaå o vaâ  àiïì  u haâ  nh àûúå c chia seã  trong quyïí n saá ch naâ y.

Comment: The properties of the PDF might show which fonts are used, if they have been embedded. It's difficult to say what the issue is, based on the information provided.

Comment: Looking at pdf properties, I see many fonts which I can't find out in Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"my computer Window 7 don't have fonts needed to read"* - it could be. Check if you have appropriate fonts, found as Randolph West says, in the pdf properties.
Another possibility is that your word can't show Vietnamese at all. Is it so?
Third possibility: Mostly languages have several code tables. You can be looking at text in one code table, while it is written in another one. This possibility could be caused by font, too, but thus we return to the first case).

Make an experiment:
Take the text, save it through PSpad (download it), as through notepad, as a file with htm extension and look at it through internet browser. There you can change the font/code table by hand.

If you can't see the text there anyway, the problem is in windows/pdf compatibility. Look out for recoding software.

If you can choose a coding to see it there, the problem is in Word. Simple font changing in Word change will help to see the text. Beware! You can see it, but you can have problems with printing or with giving it to somebody else (rather HE/SHE will have these problems). It depends on how rare the used coding table is. So, maybe, you need recoding even in this case, but you will already know from **what** to **what** the text should be translated.

Comment: Thanks. It's exact that my computer don't have fonts needed to read it. Because the font is not Unicode so Word can't display the text's font. After more googling, I finally find an online tool to recognize what base of the font and convert it to Unicode. The font's base is BK HCM 2 (not Unicode). The link for the tool is [here] (http://hanhchinhvn.com/web/chuyenma/)

Comment: @bnguyen82 be sure to mark this answer correct - it's the StackExchange way.